# sonarqube not starting on Ubuntu after restart

Tags: python, django, sonarqube, sonarscanner, sonar-project.properties

It was running and I can no longer access it using `localhost:9000`, after a restart.

I got this in the error log:

```
2023.08.30 04:57:23 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 78
2023.08.30 04:57:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2023.08.30 04:57:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
2023.08.30 05:01:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2023.08.30 05:01:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:35339]
2023.08.30 05:01:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2023.08.30 05:01:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2023.08.30 05:01:28 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 78
2023.08.30 05:01:28 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2023.08.30 05:01:28 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
sonar@ubuntu-virtual-machine:~/bin/linux-x86-64$
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to check why Elasticsearch stopped. Looks like SonarCube is dependent on it: `Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 78`